# Drawing multiple chart.js charts (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts

I'm implementing a backend application that creates multiple charts using the chart.js library and then stores them in a PNG format. I'm struggling around one problem with creating multiple charts in a for loop. Inside the for loop, the application first creates a new chart, then set its properties and then calls the createChart() function to draw the chart. After the process is finished, I'm calling chartNode.destroy() to clean up any references for a new chart.

I was expecting 12 different charts to be drawn, but 12 same charts are drawn instead. Application only draws a chart that is at the last index of textData.charts array.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
function createCharts() {
  let i = 0;
  textData.charts.forEach(graf => {
    const chartNode = new ChartjsNode(600, 600);
    setChartProperties(graf, dataResult[i]);
    createChart(graf, chartNode).then(() => {
        chartNode.destroy();
    });
    i++;
  })
}

function createChart(graf, chartNode) {
    return chartNode.drawChart(graph).then(() => {
      return chartNode.getImageBuffer('image/png');
    }).then(buffer => {
      Array.isArray(buffer)
      return chartNode.getImageStream('image/png');
    }).then(streamResult => {
      streamResult.stream
      streamResult.length
      return chartNode.writeImageToFile('image/png', './results/' + graf.filename);
    });
}
```

```js
function setChartProperties(graf, data) {
  graph.data.datasets[0].data = data;
  graph.options.title.text = graf.name;
  graph.data.labels = graf.labels;
  graph.data.datasets[1].data = graf.limits;
  graph.data.datasets[2].data = graf.limits;
  graph.data.datasets[1].backgroundColor = graf.color1;
  graph.data.datasets[2].backgroundColor = graf.color2;
  graph.data.datasets[1].borderColor = graf.color1;
  graph.data.datasets[2].borderColor = graf.color2;
  graph.data.datasets[1].label = graf.label1;
  graph.data.datasets[2].label = graf.label2;
}
```

Comment: What's in `setChartProperties`? Are there async operations in it?

Comment: see updated code, it's just setting chart.js json properties.

Comment: The problem seems to be the use of a "more global" var `graph` (I assume it's not a typo in your code and that it's a different var than `graf`). What is it exactly? it should be scoped and/or copied/created anew before calling `setChartProperties` and `createChart`

Comment: yes graph variable is a json properties default template loaded when nodejs starts. Variable graf declares specific data for each chart. I've already tried copying graph to new variable but it didn't work properly as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a shallow copy of `graph` for each of your chart constructions. If that doesn't work, just tell me, we'll try something else.

I added parameters called `graph` so that there is less things to change as possible.

```
function createCharts() {
  let i = 0;
  textData.charts.forEach(graf => {
    const chartNode = new ChartjsNode(600, 600);
    const chartGraph = Object.assign({}, graph);
    setChartProperties(chartGraph, graf, dataResult[i]);
    createChart(chartGraph, graf, chartNode).then(() => {
        chartNode.destroy();
    });
    i++;
  })
}

function createChart(graph, graf, chartNode) {
    return chartNode.drawChart(graph).then(() => {
      return chartNode.getImageBuffer('image/png');
    }).then(buffer => {
      Array.isArray(buffer)
      return chartNode.getImageStream('image/png');
    }).then(streamResult => {
      streamResult.stream
      streamResult.length
      return chartNode.writeImageToFile('image/png', './results/' + graf.filename);
    });
}

function setChartProperties(graph, graf, data) {
  graph.data.datasets[0].data = data;
  graph.options.title.text = graf.name;
  graph.data.labels = graf.labels;
  graph.data.datasets[1].data = graf.limits;
  graph.data.datasets[2].data = graf.limits;
  graph.data.datasets[1].backgroundColor = graf.color1;
  graph.data.datasets[2].backgroundColor = graf.color2;
  graph.data.datasets[1].borderColor = graf.color1;
  graph.data.datasets[2].borderColor = graf.color2;
  graph.data.datasets[1].label = graf.label1;
  graph.data.datasets[2].label = graf.label2;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, the result is still the same :/

Comment: Yeah I'm dumb, a shallow copy would lead at having the same reference value for `.data` and `.options` in `graph` copies, give me a little time to improve that..